# Eclipse shortcut key for toolbar run menu arrow?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-photon

I'm having a problem because the Eclipse menu item for re-running recent runs is so tiny. Sometimes I miss it slightly and I either hit the run button or the run with coverage button, which I then have to hit stop repeatedly and confirm a whole bunch of dialog boxes. Really annoying usability! I searched through all the key commands but couldn't find anything that would let me hit a hotkey to open the menu, like shown below when I actually manage to click that tiny down triangle.

[image: screenshot of run menu menu open]

Is there a better way? Ideally I'd just like to hit ctrl-R or cmd-R and the menu will appear, with the first one highlighted.

Currently, using Eclipse Photon.

Answer (score 1):

Standard menu shorcuts worked for me. This will open the External tools menu from menu bar

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
<kbd>E</kbd>

There's also an option to [assign a shorcut](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=88391&goto=273982&#msg_273982) to the last used external tool.
The post is old so the breadcrumb is now (unassigned by default)

> Windows -> preferences -> General -> Keys -> Run Last Launched External Tool

Comment: That's a different menu, and it only works on Windows because Windows provides those shortcuts. As you can see from the screenshot, I'm on a Mac.

Comment: So, there's no `Run` menu on Mac? If there is, the [this](https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/navigate-the-menu-bar-dock-and-more-using-your-macs-keyboard/) can help.